Estimating the Likelihood of Finding New Accessibility Issues in Mobile Applications
I have an algorithm designed to identify accessibility issues in mobile applications. The algorithm itself has some bugs (issues), and I aim to project the likelihood of discovering a new issue with the algorithm when testing additional mobile applications, given a confidence interval. Essentially, I need to determine if I need to test 5 more apps or 5000 to achieve a reliable algorithm.
Problem Context:

Total Mobile Apps: 1,000,000 (analogous to a bucket containing 1,000,000 marbles of different colors).
Applications Tested: Y (analogous to picking Y marbles from the bucket).
Distinct Issues Found: Z (analogous to finding Z distinct colors among the picked marbles).

Problem Context:

Likelihood of Finding a New Issue: How can I calculate the likelihood that, after picking Y marbles, I have found at least one marble of each of the X different colors with 99% confidence?
Projection of Total Issues: After picking Y marbles and identifying Z distinct colors, how can I project the total number of different colors in the bucket? What is the associated confidence in this projection?

My Research
I have explored capture-recapture models and the hypergeometric distribution as potential solutions. I would love pointers to the right model to use for this problem and any suggestions for videos on the model.
Thank you for your guidance!
